# A dashed line without use of stroke in Java

Tags: java, graphics, graphics2d

Is is possible to draw a dashed line(non-continues) in java by using `Graphics` but without using stroke?

For example we have `Shape line = new Line2D.Double()` but this always creates a continues line.

I need this as i have to build things(Shapes) in a seperate class and draw them in other class and i have no way to force someone to draw a dashed line if he does not use stroke.

Comment: Sorry, but the solution **is** to use an appropriate Stroke. You must arrange your code so that this is possible. It's your code, you're in control, and so only you can fix it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Stroke? I don't get the part about forcing someone to do something - Force who? Why? How would some other solution not using Stroke help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, look at the single method in the interface `Stroke`: `createStrokedShape`:

```
Stroke myStroke = ...;
Shape line = new Line2D.Double();
Shape stroked = myStroke.createStrokedShape(line);
```

And then later you can fill the stroked shape:

```
g2d.fill(stroked);
```

Comment: Thank you Erwin , this is what i was looking for :)